# python shell gives syntax error when running a print() ,however the same code executes in jupytr notebook

Tags: python

```
def test_number(x, y):
    if x == y or abs(x-y) == 5 or (x+y) == 5:
        return True
    else:
        return False

    print(test_number(7, 2))
    print(test_number(3, 2))
    print(test_number(2, 2))
```

When run in jupyter notebook, it executes with O/P:True
when run in python shell cmd, it gives invalid syntax [image: attached error image]

Comment: When defining functions inside the interactive shell, you need to enter a blank line (press enter once more) to finish defining. The prompt should change from `...`, back to `>>>`. Only then should you start writing code that's supposed to be outside the function

Comment: The three dots in your shell indicate that you are in the scope of the function definition. Press `enter` twice to exit the scope of the func and then write your print statements

Comment: came out of the scope of func and wrote the print statement, throws Nameerror: name 'true ' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Error is in the ident.
Python is an ident base language.
Correct example.

```py
def test_number(x, y):
    return x == y or abs(x-y) == 5 or (x+y) == 5

print(test_number(7, 2))
print(test_number(3, 2))
print(test_number(2, 2))
```